# Kernel panic at boot/Screen shuts off

Tags: boot, kernel, ati

if I try to boot *any* recent release. I get pages of messages regarding amd-vi io_page_fault and the kernel panics before anything happens. Or, booting in UEFI mode, the screen simply shuts off. I'm at my wit's end by now.

Specs:
AMD FX 6300
AMD Radeon R9 380 (From MSI)
8gb RAM
Mainboard: Gigabyte 970A-DS3P (IOMMU is enabled. Found that hint on another site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! Here is how:
Disable the IOMMU in the BIOS (if enabled before)
When the first purple screen appears, press any key to bring up the advanced boot menu
Hit F6 to bring up the editable boot options line.
Add iommu=soft
Continue booting. Everything should work now.
It appears to be an issue specific to Gigabyte mainboards.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your RAM/Ghaphics memory is compatible with your system. If it is , please reply.
Please also run memtest.

Comment: Currently running Windows 10 on that computer without any issues; so I assume that it is. Memtest found nothing. One thing: I tried booting with the proprietary video driver (other distribution) and it worked, but wasn't usable. The mouse pointer would snap to the edge of the screen on every click.

Comment: Did you install any updates/upgrades recently?

Comment: However it really seems like a device fault(like an IO device) or some driver fails to load and is missing or corrupted. If you have a backup , please try reverting to that instance.

Comment: Must be. I disabled iommu and it boots fine! But my mouse and keyboard are dead. At least now I know where to look.

Comment: Install the keyboard and mouse drivers for your configuration. Also check if the layout of the keyboard and mouse are set correctly. Sometimes , the drivers for different layouts are not installed by default.